# Не работает формула по смещению слайдера

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка

Подскажите, почему не получается сделать, чтобы смещался слайдер? Пишу сам, решил сдвигать при помощи margin-left сам ul. В консоли все работало. Что-то не так с формулой (преобразования строк в число, сложение числа со строкой и т.д.). У меня curSlidePos содержит "0px", slideWidth - число 300, свойство margin-left должно стать - 300px. Что не так-то?)

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('right-a')) {
        sliderUl.css('margin-left', '(+(curSlidePos) - slideWidth) + px');
        curSlideCount++;
    }
```

Comment: `sliderUl.css('margin-left', (curSlidePos - slideWidth) + 'px');`

Comment: Не срабатывает. Все равно после нажатия на '.right-a' sliderUl.css('margin-left') = '0px'

Comment: а ну да..... `(+(curSlidePos) - slideWidth) + 'px'`  или `(parseInt(curSlidePos) - slideWidth) + 'px'`